# Windows command to delete eldest and second eldest folder on drive?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I want to delete the oldest and second eldest folder from a drive using a Windows Command Line script.

This is running from BackupAssist, which only supports windows command line commands/DOS in the GUI for pre or post-backup scripts. I'd rather not write a command line to call into a Powershell script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find the oldest and next oldest directories in the current directory. Comment out the `echo` commands and uncomment the `rd` commands to make it functional.

```
@echo off
rem cmd file to delete oldest and second oldest directories
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/ad-l/o-d') do @set nextoldest=!oldest! & SET oldest=%%i
echo %oldest%
echo %nextoldest%
rem rd /s/q %oldest%
rem rd /s/q %nextoldest%
```

If you want to make it look at the whole drive, change the `dir` command to look like this:

```
dir /b/ad-l/o-d/s \
```

That will take a long time.

Note that I excluded junction points with `-l`.